# support library in Eclipse vs AndroidStudio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I tried to build Eclipse project that references android.support.design library (CoordinatorLayout and FAB inside it). I copied into my workspace android.support.v7.recyclerview library project and sucesfuly built it. Then did the same with appcompat-v7. That enabled me to build design library (previously also copied into workspace) which goes OK. Finally I built project, that references design library. Everything went well, designer presented good preview (API23), but running on device (API 17) didn't succeed- LogCat express disability to inflate CoordinatorLayout. TargetSDK was 17 and compilerSDk was 23. My support library is 23.1 version.

When making the same project in Android Studio (everything was wizard generated), I faced no problems. I noticed the same dependencies in gradle file, and SDKs are same as in Eclipse. Why those diferencies and where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You mean you have problems on Eclipse but none in Android Studio? Try lowering the compilerSDk or raising the TargetSDK to the latest release.

Comment: Yes it doesn't work using Eclipse. I raised TargetSDK to 23 gave no result. Thane recompiled appcompat-V7, recyclerview, and design libraries to API21 and project itself, also to 21, but error persists.